# IONIC - accessing to API

Tags: json, angular, api, ionic-framework, get

I want to access data through the API. But my application does not receive any data. Can someone help me please?
Code from providers/rest:

```
      getAnimes() 
  {
    var url ='https://akihabara.cz/api/api.php?co=%7B"hledat"%3A%7B"text"%3A"s"%2C"kde"%3A"dorama"%7D%2C"prihlaseni"%3A%7B"token"%3A"xxx"%7D%7D';
    var response = this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
    return response;
  }
```

When I write it to the browser it generates data, but my app does not.
Code from home.ts:

```
export class HomePage {
  animes: Array<any>;

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public restProvider: RestProvider, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
        this.getAnimes();
      }
      getAnimes() {
        this.restProvider.getAnimes().subscribe((data)=>{this.animes = data;
        });
      }
    }
```

And finally code from home.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Anime</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list inset>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let anime of animes">
      <h2>{{anime}}</h2>
      <p>{{anime.nalezeno}}</p>

    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**Array from browser:**
"nalezeno":{"pocet":2,1:{"id":541, "nazevjap":"Hassai-sensei","pristupnost":"0"},2:{"id":3236, "nazevjap":"Ssairen","pristupnost":"0"}};

Answer (score 0):

import rxjs map and use subscribe method and your api have lot's of data so you can  also use pagination for that and first try with res.text() beacuse according to browser response it's not valid json please use this https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer link for verify api response have valid json or not  so for now try with res.text() first for get response

```
   import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; 

   this.http.get('https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD').map(res => 
        res.json()).subscribe(data => {
          console.info(data)
         },(reject) => {
           console.info(reject)
         })
```

if you need data in text form then use res.text()

if you need data in json form then use res.json()

Answer (score 0):

Your [URL](https://akihabara.cz/api/api.php?co=%7B%22hledat%22%3A%7B%22text%22%3A%22s%22%2C%22kde%22%3A%22dorama%22%7D%2C%22prihlaseni%22%3A%7B%22token%22%3A%22xxx%22%7D%7D) is not returning back valid **JSON**, but you are trying to convert that data into **JSON** in

> map(res => res.json());

so this `res.json()` throws error when code tries to convert it to JSON.

and as you are not handling errors so you are unable to find what is wrong with it.

if you use following code

```
getAnimes() {
  this.restProvider.getAnimes().subscribe(
    (data) => {this.animes = data;
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Your code will always move into error block.

**Solution** : Either change response to valid JSON or remove `=> res.json()`